# How to control and react to events outside ngapp

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to build an angular app on SharePoint (this question is not related to SharePoint though).

I have a page where which has a div that has angular app directive (Its a form with bunch of text boxes). The page has other components on it, which reside outside the ngapp like Ribbon control and I specifically do not have control on it.

Typically if its a jquery app, I would write document.ready function and add my custom components to the ribbon using SharePoint javascript api and wireup any events required like Save, cancel.

I would like to accomplish similar using angularjs if possible. The problem is since they reside outside ngapp I do not understand how to initialize and wire up events.

In specific I would like to know how to accomplish below.

a) Initialize ribbon buttons, which reside outside ngapp. I do not have control on specifics of html. I can only tell api to add a button on ready. In short I would like to call some code when dom is ready to initialize some UI controls that reside outside of ngapp.

b) When user clicks on that button, I would like my app to react to it.

I would like to know if its possible.

Ex:

```
<body>
<div>
//some area I do not have direct control over but would like to 
//initialize and react to events in angular
</div>  
<div ng-app="myApp">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first things first.
1 initialize your ribons buttons the same way you would do it w/o the angular app, use jquery if you want, jquery and angular play well together, so no harm there
except in the buttons events add this peace of code

if using jquery

```
var rootScope=angular.element($('[ng-app]')[0]).scope()
```

this will give you the rootScope of your app and once there if you want to pass values to your app you can either attach the values to the rootScope or use

```
rootScope.$broadcast()
```

to broadcast events in any case always remember to use

```
rootScope.$apply()
```

otherwise angular will not be aware of the changes immediately.

there are other ways, using the app injector to get hold on a service or a value and make your update there, 
you can also set localStorage values and have angular to watch those values. but the firs approach is the most straigt  forward